# How to process a input array in laravel API

Tags: api, laravel

MY Input array for API is

```
{
"task": "34"
"approver": 
{
["id": "40"],
["id": "41"] 
}
}
```

I want to insert the data in approvers table wherein each task can have multiple approver's. So new row for each approver id.

Below is my code

```
$event_id = Input::get('event_id');
$approver[] = Input::get('approver');

foreach ($approver as $id)
{
$user = new Approver;
$user->event_id = $event_id;
$user->approver_id = $id['id'];
$saved = $user->save();    
}
```

I am getting null as all the variables. What is the proper way to receive the data ?

Output :

```
$input = Input::all();

return Response::json(array(
                    'error' => false,
                    'message' => $input),
                    200
                );
```

Output response I get is

```
{
"error": false
"message": [0]
}
```

Comment: You are pushing data to `$approver` array with this line `$approver[] = <...>` as new element. You can easily write `$approver = Input::get('approver', []);` and it would be good to go, because `Input::get('approver')` will return array.

Comment: It returns null, even event_id is been return as NULL. Is smething worng with the input array ?

Comment: Attach what is returned upon `dd(Input::all())` command.

Comment: I have added the response on the post, Regards..

Comment: As You can see, no data reaching Your controller, that's why You got null on every variable. The problem is in the sender (view?).